# create dynamically table from mysql result with rowspan

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I create a HTML table from Mysql output in this way:

```
$i = 0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    if ( $i == 0 ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ( array_keys($row) as $fieldName ) echo "<th>".$fieldName."</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ( $row as $value ) echo "<td>".$value."</td>";      
    echo "</tr>";   
    $i++;
}
```

If there are two or more identical cells with one another in a column, then this cells should be automatically **joined** using the HTML attribute `rowspan`

I am not able to find a solution for dynamically create a table with joined cells in the same **column**.

Comment: with what you have, you can't. You're just dealing with each value as its own isolated little universe. If you want to combine cells, then you need to "look around" in your arrays to see what's coming up and adjust your output.

Comment: Could you please add an example of the datas you have and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to change the rowspan, you have to do 2 things :

- Check the next values in that column to know how many are the same
- Check the previous rowspan value to avoid printing a value that
  should not (because the previous one had a rowspan > 1)

Here is some code with example values so that you can test it. The first `foreach()` has to be replaced by `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {` to make it work with your database's datas.

```
// Example datas for tests
$rows = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'Product 1',
        'price' => 20,
        'option_x_included' => 'No',
        'duration' => 12
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Product 2',
        'price' => 30,
        'option_x_included' => 'Yes',
        'duration' => 12
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Product 3',
        'price' => 45,
        'option_x_included' => 'Yes',
        'duration' => 18
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => 'Product 4',
        'price' => 60,
        'option_x_included' => 'Yes',
        'duration' => 24
    )
);

echo '<table>';

$i = 0;
$rowspanValues = array();
foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
// Replace this foreach (for tests) by:
// while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // First row: Column headers
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach (array_keys($row) as $fieldName) {
            echo '<th>'.$fieldName.'</th>';

            // Init rowspan value for each column
            $rowspanValues[$fieldName] = 1;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // Other rows: Values
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $value) {

        if ($rowspanValues[$fieldName] == 1) {
        // rowspan for that column is 1: means that we have not tested next values

            // Test if next values in the same column is the same
            $nextIndex = $index+1;
            while (!empty($rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName]) && $value == $rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName]) {
                // Increment nextIndex to test the row after
                $nextIndex++;

                // Increment current rowspan value
                $rowspanValues[$fieldName]++;
            }

            // Put the calculated rowspan to current cell
            echo '<td rowspan="'.$rowspanValues[$fieldName].'">'.$value.'</td>'; 
        } else {
        // rowspan value > 1: means that the previous column had a bigger rowspan, so this cell must not been printed
            $rowspanValues[$fieldName]--;
        }

    }    
    echo '</tr>';   
    $i++;
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem. Now I made some minor changes to your code to make it work better with the MySql result and it seems to me there was a little failure, because the index went over the number of rows. This code I will now submit as answer to my post.

Comment: After working a while with your suggestion, I see that there are some other problems: On the last row of the table I get the PHP error: `Notice: Undefined offset` This is not very serious, but I would be glad to have a workaround. And a second problem ocurred: If the last cell in the last row is empty than obviously it runs in an endless loop. But I don't find out why.

I suppose that a solution of the first problem will solve the second.

Comment: I know that the `Undefined offset` error raises, because if we have the last row, than `$rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName])` is undefined because there is no nextIndex available on the last row.

Comment: To fix the `Undefined offset` error, try replacing the `while` line by: `while (!empty($rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName]) && $value == $rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName]) {`.

Comment: I don't manage to reproduce the endless loop. Could you tell me if the `while` update fixed it, and if not, give me an example of the datas I should use to reproduce it?

Comment: Thank you. With the condition `! empty($rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName])` both problems seem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $con);

$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) $rows[] = $row;

echo "<table>";
foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
    // First row: Column headers
    if ($index == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach (array_keys($row) as $fieldName) {
            echo '<th>'.$fieldName.'</th>';

            // Init rowspan value for each column
            $rowspanValues[$fieldName] = 1;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    // Other rows: Values
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $value) {

        if ($rowspanValues[$fieldName] == 1) {
        // rowspan for that column is 1: means that we have not tested next values

            // Test if next values in the same column is the same
            $nextIndex = $index + 1;            
            while ($value == $rows[$nextIndex][$fieldName]) {
                // Increment nextIndex to test the row after
                $nextIndex++;

                // Increment current rowspan value
                $rowspanValues[$fieldName]++;
            }

            // Put the calculated rowspan to current cell
            echo '<td rowspan="'.$rowspanValues[$fieldName].'">'.$value.'</td>'; 
        } else {
        // rowspan value > 1: means that the previous column had a bigger rowspan, so this cell must not been printed
            $rowspanValues[$fieldName]--;
        }
    }    
    echo '</tr>';   
}
echo '</table>';
```